# How to use express validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, validation

i need validator to check for error and log into console if any

here is my code below;

```
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/add-page', function(req, res){
check("title", "Title must have a value.").not().isEmpty();
check("content", "Content must have a value.").not().isEmpty();


var title = req.body.title;
var slug = req.body.slug.replace(/\#+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
if (slug == "") {
    slug = title.replace(/\#+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
}

var content = req.body.content;
var errors = validationResult(req);
if (errors){
    console.error(errors);
    
    
    res.render("admin/add_page",{
        errors: errors,
        title:title,
        slug:slug,
        content:content
    });
} else {
   Page.findOne({slug:slug}, function(err, page){
       if (page) {
           req.flash("danger","Page slug exists, choose another.");
           res.render("admin/add_page",{
            
            title:title,
            slug:slug,
            content:content
        });
       } else {
           var Page = new Page({
               title:title,
               slug:slug,
               content:content,
               sorting:0
           });
           Page.save(function(err){
               if (err) {
                   return console.log(err);
                   
               } else {
                   req.flash("Success", "Page added!");
                   res.redirect("/admin/pages");
               }
           })
       }
   })
    
}

});



//Exports
module.exports = router;
```

But my result in console is

```
Result { formatter: [Function: formatter], errors: [] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in your router definition an array of every validation which you want to perform on each request which is handle by a given route.

like this

```
router.post(route_path, [...], function(req, res) {});
```

For your specific case It will look like this

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/add-page', [
    check("title", "Title must have a value.").not().isEmpty(),
    check("content", "Content must have a value.").not().isEmpty()
], function(req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors);


        return res.status(500).json({
            errors
        });

        /*
        return res.render("admin/add_page",{
            errors: errors,
            title:title,
            slug:slug,
            content:content
        });
        */
    }

    // And the other code goes when validation succeed 
}
```

Comment: Your are welcome, when question have answer you must mark it as resolved and upvote the answer if It was helpful

Answer (score 2):

What you should be logging is

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
   console.log(res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() }));
 }
```

This is the correct way of logging errors in express validator [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/). Whenever a request that includes invalid fields is submitted, your server will respond like this:

```
{
 "errors": [{
   ... //fields
  }]
}
```

For all the available validators in express-validator (just like its options), take a look at validator.js docs [here](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#validators).

Answer (score 0):

express is a middleware framework
express-validator is used to validate the request for that we need to call the validator before the request is actually passed for that we use express validator
before the callback method you have to check for the validation for that you will pass a middleware before the callback

here how you suppose to do that

```
router.post(
  "/add-page",
  [
    check("title", "Title must have a value.").not().isEmpty(),
    check("content", "Content must have a value.").not().isEmpty(),
  ],
   (req, res) => {
    try {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors);//if client get any error the code will pass here you can do anything according to your choice
        });

      } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```